# Getting Purely Associative Array from JSON data

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to work with the JSON returned by these URLs:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.0,12.0&sensor=false

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.76144296429947,-104.8011589050293&sensor=false

Here's what I've done:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.0,12.0&sensor=false';
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ), true );
print_r( $data );
```

And here's the output:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
       [address_components] => Array (
           [0] => Array (
               [long_name] => Chungul Jabarari-Dabalam-Jajere Road
               [short_name] => Chungul Jabarari-Dabalam-Jajere Road
               [types] => Array ( [0] => route ) )
           [1] => Array (
               [long_name] => Yobe [short_name] => Yobe
               [types] => Array (
                   [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                   [1] => political ) )
           [2] => Array (
               [long_name] => Nigeria
               [short_name] => NG
               [types] => Array (
                    [0] => country
                    [1] => political ) )
 ....
```

As you can see, `address_components` is under `[0]` which makes it difficult to work with this result set when the number of arrays is unknown.

**Let's say I want to get the `administrative_area_level_2` which is the County in the US, but apparently doesn't exist in Nigeria?**

**Then let's say I want to access the country which is `['results'][0]['address_components'][6]` in the USA but is `['results'][0]['address_components'][3]` in Nigeria**

What I'm asking for is an efficient way of accessing each element of data in this array when the number of sub arrays is unreliable.

(Or alternatively decoding the JSON better to produce an array that doesn't have these useless indexes and is just a purely associative array.)

Comment: Use `var_dump` to inspect $data; that is, $data now contains a *normal* PHP array/map. There is *no* "JSON" involved any longer as JSON is only the *text markup*. When such questions are asked, make sure to include a minimal and relevant sample (that reproduces the behavior/problem) in the question itself.

Comment: It will not work as json decode returning an object. You can not handle it as array

Comment: @user2864740 and others, changed the question to hopefully explain the problem better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727981/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-type-of-administrative-area-level-1-2-etc.  Things like administrative_area_level_2 do not have a fixed definition across all countries/regions. What is your reasoning for wanting to look up based on that?

Comment: when you dont know how the json will be structured, you need to implement recursive logic to parse that data. it should check if it is an array or a value

Comment: @PatrickQ The definition doesn't really matter. It just the value of the administrative_area_level_2 that I want, if it's present, no matter what it's definition is for that area. The question linked is not a duplicate with all due respect.

Comment: The title of the linked question is "How do I get the name of the type of administrative_area_level_1, 2, etc". You just said "It just the value of the administrative_area_level_2 that I want, if it's present". I fail to see the difference.

Comment: @PatrickQ He's asking for the `type` (state/province). I just want the value. Not same question. I'm my case the problem is how to get this value knowing that sometimes it will be in sub array indexed [3] and sometimes in sub array indexed [7] or any other index depending on location.

Comment: While I still think those are two sides of the same coin, see my updated answer.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thank you for answer Patrick it appears that it is indeed as good as it's going to get. But without wanting to appear insisting, the question you marked as duplicate is asking "How do I know if the admin_area_level_1 is called a 'State' or a 'Province' in the (ie) USA". All I want is to know if admin_area_1 is California, I don't care if it would be called a province in Canada or a State in the USA. He wants the `type`, I want the `value`. Thanks though.

Comment: So my answer does or does not do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the name if `administrative_area_level_2` is present, and "N/A" if not present. Note that is is probably somewhat inefficient (looping and checking something that might not be there), but it could very well be as good as it gets for something like this.

```
function getAdminAreaLevel2($data)
{
    foreach($data['results'][0]['address_components'] as $component)
    {
        if(in_array("administrative_area_level_2", $component['types']))
        {
            return $component['long_name'];
        }
    }

    return "N/A";
}

echo getAdminAreaLevel2($firstData);
echo "\r\n";
echo getAdminAreaLevel2($secondData);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe9c6f29bec9f66b67407f43fa291e9b9d2d81ed)

Comment: Thanks but actually the country is just an example. What if I wanted to get the `administrative_area_level_2` IF it exists (it doesn't in Nigeria apparently). I would like an efficient way of accessing the data no matter how many arrays are in `address_components`

Comment: You should really put exactly what you want in your question. Otherwise we're just wasting our time.

Comment: Sorry it was not my intention. Your answer does work but it only works to get the country, which I gave as a (bad) example. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you this answer does work. I'm still hoping a more flexible may come along.

Comment: More flexible in what way? I'd be glad to update, but as it stands, your requirements/specs seem rather vague.

Comment: I understand, it's my first time working with JSON and JSON decoded PHP arrays so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. I will eventually be needing to access every bit of information available in `address_components` and hopefully end up with an associative array that I can use like `$location['country']...$location['street']` etc. While I could build this array from the solution you offered, like you I feel it may be too inefficient for what's going to be a feature on a live site. I may have to rethink this whole feature :)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is making an API request for each component that you want. This requires either an API key or a clientID, and may be even less efficient than using a custom parsing function for each component (making a handful of API requests vs just one). You can see in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) that a `result_type` parameter can be used to filter the results. I'd probably go with the parser, but this would be an option. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = json_decode($url,true);

$address_component = false;
foreach($data['results'] as $value) {

   if(isset($value['address_components'])) {

        $address_component = $value['address_components'];
        break;

    }
}
if($address_component) {
    echo $address_component[6]['long_name'];
}
```

Comment: This only works when the location is in the USA. As I said in my question, to get the country in a Nigerian location for example it would be `address_components[3]`. So this solution doesn't work for all locations.